# Tableau: time series chart displaying last day of month instead of first

Tags: date, tableau-api, timeserieschart

In any time series chart, it looks like Tableau defaults to the first day of the month on the tick marks.

Is there a way for Tableau to show the last day of the month instead?

You can sort of force it by going into "Edit Axis", starting it on a month end, and 1 as the monthly interval.  However, this is not a dynamic process and would require that I update this every time I had new data.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If in your data series you want each data point to represent the whole month, and you just want to label it with the last date of that month, then this workaround might work:

- use calculated field to coerce all dates in the month to the last date of that month: `DATEADD('day',-1,DATEADD('month',1,DATETRUNC('month',[Order Date])))`
- use this field as date in your time series
- use 'More -> Custom -> Month / Day /Year' as display option for this field